# Failed to use import mysql.connector , have already installed Connector/Python for MySQL successfully

Tags: python, mysql

I have downloaded the Connector/Python for MySQL successfully. I used the following code in Python's shell to test my connection:  `import mysql.connector`

I received the following error message:

> No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package.

I have already tried to install mysql.connector through:
`C:\Users\HP>pip install mysql-connector-python`

This is also not working

Comment: What error do you get when you do `pip install mysql-connector-python`? What's your python version?

Comment: did u import  ```import  mysql.connector```  in ur python file at the top ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to a `Python` version issues. If you are using `Python3.x` then use

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

to install the python package. Then importing

```
import mysql.connector
```

in an interpreter or a script would work perfectly fine.

Comment: Have the same python , and tried 
pip3 install mysql-connector for installing 
stilll the same problem .

Comment: Do look around online for possible solutions. if not i will jump in and do my best